# Is there a jQuery approach to pretty urls

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, url-rewriting, pretty-urls

Is there a way I can implement a url like "www.example.com/profiles/male/johndoe" without any . htaccess code?
The reason is that . htaccess is too complicated for my understanding, the little htaccess code I've been able to write keep clashing with my relative path and won't work on live server (it is working on WAMP local server).
So I'm looking for a jquery or JavaScript approach. I've read a lot about URI.js I don't know how to use it to achieve my aim.
Any help will appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Unless you use a Node.js server, JavaScript runs on the client and cannot help you.  You need to learn .htaccess or another server-side routing engine.

Comment: Short answer is ...No

Comment: Oh, thanks. I'll have to suspend the project and learn htaccess properly

Comment: Actually you are not having problems with ".htaccess", but with request rewriting. You want to read the documentation instead of trying around with snippets you find.